# Unix: shared memory. shm_open() returns -1

Tags: linux, unix, posix, shared-memory

**Note**: the actual problem was with using fork() function. So the solution is found.

---

```
 //create shared memoery
        int shmfd;
        void *shared_memory = (void *)0;
        shmfd = shm_open("/shm2_rev_to_upp", O_RDWR | O_CREAT | O_EXCL, 0666); //reverse to upper
        if (shmfd == -1) {
           perror("shm_open");
           exit(1);
        }

        if(ftruncate(shmfd, sizeof(struct shared_use_st)) == -1){
          perror("ftruncate");
          exit(1);
        }

        shared_memory = mmap(NULL, sizeof(struct shared_use_st), PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, shmfd, 0);

        if(shared_memory == MAP_FAILED){
          perror("mmap");
          exit(1);
        }

    //some code here

    munmap(shared_memory, sizeof(struct shared_use_st));
    shm_unlink("/shm2_rev_to_upp");
    close(shmfd);
```

I got this error in the runtime

```
shm_open: File exists
```

Then `shm_open() return -1` why is that?!!
Note that the first couple of times I run the program, the error does not show up!!

How can I fix this problem?!

Answer (score 2):

```cpp
shmfd = shm_open("/shm2_rev_to_upp", O_RDWR | O_CREAT | O_EXCL, 0666);

modify:  shmfd = shm_open("/shm2_rev_to_upp", O_RDWR | O_CREAT, 0666);
```

Answer (score 1):

The man page explains the various error codes:

> `EEXIST`: Both O_CREAT and O_EXCL were specified to shm_open() and the  shared memory object specified by name already exists.

Comment: could you explain more please?!! I did not get it.

Comment: how could i fix the problem?!!

Comment: I thought that `shm_unlink()` and `munmap()` will fix the problem.

Comment: @AZSH  The reason why it does that is because you don't ALWAYS shm_unlink the shared memory.  For example when this code executes `if(ftruncate(shmfd, sizeof(struct shared_use_st)) == -1){ perror("ftruncate"); exit(1); }` or this code executes `if(shared_memory == MAP_FAILED){ perror("mmap"); exit(1); }` then the shm_unlink never happens.

Comment: I see. this helped understand more about shared memory but the problem was with fork() function which is not included in the question.

Comment: Since the actual problem is not related to my question, should I delete this question or I just leave it like this?!